# Need to parse thousands of files for thousands of results - prefer powershell

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I am getting consistently pinged from our government contract holder to search for IP addresses in our logs.  I have three firewalls, 30 plus servers, etc so you can imagine how unwieldy it becomes.  To amplify the problem, I have been provided a list of over 1500 IP addresses for which I am to search all log files...

I have all of the logs downloaded and can use powershell to go through them one by one but it takes forever.  I need to be able to run the search using multi-thread in Powershell but cannot figure out the logic to do so.  Here's my one by one script...

Any help would be appreciated!

```
$log = (import-csv C:\temp\FWLogs\IPSearch.csv)
$ip = ($log.IP)
ForEach($log in $log){ Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\temp\FWLogs -filter *.log | Select-String $ip -List | Select Path
}
```

Comment: Have a look into [`ForEach-Object -Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1#example-12--retrieve-log-entries-in-parallel).

Comment: [`about_Jobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs?view=powershell-7.1) and [`about_Thread_Jobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_thread_jobs?view=powershell-7.1) might also be helpful ([`ThreadJob` on PSGallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ThreadJob/2.0.3) if you're using PowerShell 5.1 or lower)